# Error handling for json-schema redefined type_checker in python

Tags: python, jsonschema, python-jsonschema

I'm using [json-schema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) to validate a schema. I wanted to customize the date-time type. So, redefined the type accordingly and extended the validator. But, it's not returning the error the way I'm looking for. My code:

```
        BaseVal = jsonschema.Draft202012Validator
    def date_time(checker, instance):
        return datetime.strptime(instance, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    timedatechecker = BaseVal.TYPE_CHECKER.redefine('date-time', date-time)
    Validator = jsonschema.validators.extend(BaseVal, type_checker=timedatechecker)

    errors = sorted(Validator(schema=schema).iter_errors(json), key=lambda e: e.path)
```

The errors variable currently contains all the errors during the schema validation, for example, id, age, etc., but not the error that occurs at datetime. I'm returning the errors list from the validation function. It returns True when there's no error, and the error list otherwise. When I POST a wrong datetime input from postman, it returns 500 Internal Server Error, and vscode shows this error message in terminal:

> strptime raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r",
> %ValueError: time data '2015-01-35T05:05:05' does not match format
> '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

How can I make json-schema catch it, so I can use it from errors? Or any other workaround that'd achieve the same I'm trying to get. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The format is called `date-time`, not `datetime`.

However, it would be much better for you to define a new format rather than redefine an existing one, as redefining formats breaks interoperability.

Comment: Tried redefining date-time, with same outcome as before. Is there any specific way to define new format? Not finding any explicit example here: https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validate/#jsonschema.TypeChecker.redefine . Tried adding a custom name instead of date-time in the above code, didn't work as well

Comment: The ability to define new formats is optional, so your implementation may not support it. I suggest you open a feature request in its issue tracker.